# Can't transfer image while pushing ViewController

Tags: swift

I have tableView, in which there are imageView and label, when i select cell I want to push another viewController and show in it my selected cell imageView.image and label.text, but there is error that (Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value) in image line

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PushedViewController") as? PushedViewController
    vc?.pushedImage.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
    vc?.pushedLabel.text = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: On which line do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

you've posted not too much, but it seems the crashing line is

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)`

are you sure this `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PushedViewController") as? PushedViewController` is not `nil`?

maybe `PushedViewController` is not in the same storyboard. Anyway just put it in a `guard let` to unwrap the optional

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PushedViewController") as? PushedViewController else { //fallback goes here return }
    vc.pushedImage.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
    vc.pushedLabel.text = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first view controller `selectedImage` and `selectedText` will be nil in `tableView didSelectRowAt` method. The `IBOutlet`s will be initiated only after you've pushed the second view controller. So create a `UIImage` and `String` variables in the second view controller and send values to these variables. In the second view controller's `viewDidLoad` method assign the passed values to the `IBOutlet`s.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PushedViewController") as? PushedViewController
    //vc?.pushedImage vc?.pushedLabel are nil
    vc?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
    vc?.selectedText = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

PushedViewController

```
class PushedViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var pushedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pushedImage: UIImageView!
    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    var selectedText: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //vc?.pushedImage vc?.pushedLabel are not nil
        pushedImage.image = selectedImage
        pushedLabel.text = selectedText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UI components is not yet initialised, so you can not access them right after you initialise the controller.

I'd suggest you to have a local variable in the `PushedViewController` to store image and text and then assign those in `viewDidLoad`.

Like this:

```
class PushedViewController: UIViewController {
    //..
    var image:UIImage?
    var text:String?
    //..
    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //..
        if let image = self.image {
            self.imageView.image = image
        }
        if let text = self.text {
            self.label.text = text
        }
        //..
    }
    //..
}
```

Then set those properties from where you are pushing the controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PushedViewController") as? PushedViewController else { return }
    // Assign the properties here
    vc.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
    vc.text = textsArray[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```